# Automatic re-indentation

Tags: indentation

I'm using Emacs to write ocaml programs, and the automatic indentation works fine : suppose I write `if` in the middle of a line, then skip a line and write `then` ; the keyword `then` is automatically aligned with my `if`.

But if I later decide to add some code before the `if`, and the position of the `if` thus changes, `then` remains aligned with the previous position of the `if` until I manually add (and immediately remove) a lineskip on the line that has my `then` so that the indentation is recalculated.

Is there a way to ask Emacs to reindent all lines in my document without having to add-and-remove lineskips everywhere to force Emacs to recalculate the correct indentation line by line?

Comment: I had never heard the word` lineskip` used in this way.  Usually we call it "newline" or "LF".

Comment: Have you tried the `indent-buffer` interactive function (`M-x indent-buffer`)?  `indent-region` may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the TAB key (`indent-for-tab-command`) reindents the current line and `C-M-\` (`indent-region`) reindents the region.

Answer (score 0):

For a completely automated solution use the package [aggressive-indent](https://github.com/Malabarba/aggressive-indent-mode).